# JSON encode and decode on PHP

Tags: php, json

I have JSON output encoded.

```
$responseJSON
{"status":1,"content":{"sessionid":"4c86cf1acac07811db6ec670e0b9cdd2"}}
```

now I do a decode on that

```
$decoded=json_decode($responseJSON);

print_r($decoded)
```

I get

```
stdClass Object (
  [status] => 1 
  [content] => stdClass Object ( 
    [sessionid] => 4c86cf1acac07811db6ec670e0b9cdd2 
  ) 
)
```

I don't want decoded like that.

how do I decode to an normal array without those stdClass tag?

Comment: As a side note, `stdClass` is a special generic class used for objects not constructed from a normal class.  These [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting) explain in a little more detail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't have enough rep to comment on other peoples comments

To get the info out after you've processed it with

```
$decoded = json_decode( $responseJSON, TRUE );
```

You can access all the information inside of it as normal.
do a

```
var_dump($decoded);
```

just incase it add's levels you wouldn't expect
Then just proceed as usual

```
echo $decoded['status']
echo $decoded['content']['sessionid']
```

Answer (score 6):

try

```
json_decode($responseJSON,true);
```

the `true` tells php to generate associative arrays

Answer (score 5):

[`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) second argument can be `TRUE` which will force all objects to be read in as a PHP associated arrays.

```
$decoded = json_decode( $responseJSON, TRUE );
```

[PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

> When TRUE (referring to the second argument), returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Comment: after decoding how do I extract the data inside $decoded->status? I am not not getting anything.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$decoded=json_decode($responseJSON, TRUE);
```

Comment: after decoding how do I extract the data inside $decoded->status? $decoded->content->sessionid? I am not getting anything like that.

Comment: @lilzz, since it is an array, you'd want to use array notation, like $decoded['status'].