# Push a value inside an array in a json in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json like this {"1":["3","5","6","2","4","1"],"2":[]} and I want to push a value inside the array in the key "2" so I want to do like this {"1":["3","5","6","2","4","1"],"2":["myvalue"]}.
I've tried many ways but no luck.
This is what I tried

```
      /// json = {"1":["3","5","6","2","4","1"],"2":[]}
        $arrayparole= $json["2"];
        array_push($arrayparole,"myvalue");

        $json = $json + array("2"=>$arrayparole); 
          $record = json_encode($json);
```

but doesn't work.
Can you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON encode and decode on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707618/json-encode-and-decode-on-php)

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you have is basically a string. Therefore you cannot access the JSON using the index like you did.
What you need to do is to convert the JSON string into Array first. After you have the array, only you are able to access the values using index/keys.
You can only push value into an array.

You cannot append array to a string like you did.

```
$json = $json + array("2"=>$arrayparole);
```

Following are example of converting the string into array and use array_push to insert new value.

```php
$jsonstring = '{"1":["3","5","6","2","4","1"],"2":[]}';

// decode the JSON string into Array
$array = json_decode($jsonstring, true);

// once you have the array, you can now push your value
array_push($array[2],"myvalue");

// now you can convert back the array to json
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: @fabrizio if this answer is helpful, kindly mark it as the Answer

Comment: Thank you Afif. I'll check today afternoon and I'll mark as answer if it is ok.
Stupid question just to understand: why you say that it is a string?